# canvas element seems like it is padded, however css says it is not

Tags: css, p5.js

In my p5.js code, [original code here](https://editor.p5js.org/jfenn2002@gmail.com/sketches/Z-3spAygm), I want the canvas to be aligned with the top left of the screen. However, the canvas does not seem to want to co-operate, and it looks like there is a padding on the top of the canvas.

When the display class in CSS is set to block (the default), the canvas appears to have a padding on the top, however you cannot change this using CSS. All I want is for the canvas to be aligned to the top left.

I have tried manipulating CSS, using padding-top, padding, block: inline, and overflow: hidden, but they have not worked, however, block: inline seems to change the canvas so the padding is on the left instead of the top.

Simply, I try to do this in my sketch:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 600);
}

function draw() {
  draw_my_stuff_here();
}
```

However this code works normally, however, it seems the stuff in draw_my_stuff_here(); something causes this problem happens.

A simpler version, [found here](https://editor.p5js.org/jfenn2002@gmail.com/sketches/7hvhII81Q), is a very similar setup, but actually works. The difference is it doesn't use the SceneManager. 
A version that uses SceneManager with just a rectangle works, and can be [found here](https://editor.p5js.org/jfenn2002@gmail.com/sketches/7uyOy24P1).

I want the top left of the canvas to be aligned with the top left of the screen, but it doesn't do this and I'm not sure why. my debugging hasn't fixed it. I've looked on p5.js github, but couldn't find any very similar issues, and to be honest the problem is probably in my code (and not an issue with p5.js).

In my code, I am using a lib that allows me to have different scenes, so the code that actually is running (the draw function), is in game.js. You will find the code I have written there.

Comment: Have you considered that it may be the page that is padded? Have you set padding: 0, margin: 0 on the page? Alternatively, is the canvas set to position: absolute, left: 0, top: 0?

Comment: Can you please narrow your problem down to a simplified [mcve]? Just draw a single rectangle and check for the padding issue.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I simplified it a little and edited my post to include a simpler version but the problem isn't happening in that one. I don't think it will help but this also makes me think it could be a problem with the library p5.SceneManager.js since I don't use that one in the simpler version.

Comment: @Andrea I tried setting the position to what you said, but I think I am formatting it incorrectly. Could you put an example in a code block for me?

Answer (score 1):

I would be interested to see what setting the padding, margin (and maybe even border) on the HTML and Body would do.

```
html, body {
  border: 0px; 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Try this out, looks like your original CSS for the canvas element has some commas where there should be semi-colons.

```
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this on html, body and on the canvas, one at a time and together, and it hasn't worked.

Comment: Ah ha - I think I see an error in your CSS. Can you try this for the canvas element? canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

Comment: yeah someone above you also mentioned this. I was having trouble formatting it but it worked out

Comment: Yup Andreas answer was just formatted incorrectly. I edited my answer to include properly formatted CSS for the Canvas element, tested in p5.js

Comment: yeah I wasn't trying to write syntactically correct CSS in my comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was having was it was ambiguous where the canvas should go, so CSS does whatever it wants with the canvas. By doing

```
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

It forced CSS to place it in the top left. Thanks to @Andrea and @jdevo for coming up with the solution to my problem.